# TSQL- need help in total day not week

Tags: t-sql, group-by

Hi I'm struggling with the following problem.
I have two tables one with employee info name and id's the second is a time-sheet table.

```
Name        date_entered             durhr   part_no        TotalHours
Ajay Singh  2012-02-06 09:58:02.440  0.25   ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-08 07:47:50.720  0.25   ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-08 11:15:17.110  0.25   ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-09 09:35:20.360  0.25   ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-06 09:57:43.373  0.5    ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-06 09:57:52.407  0.5    ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-09 09:35:09.193  0.5    ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-10 14:23:38.893  0.5    ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-09 09:16:36.327  0.75   AD-CREATE       43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-09 09:24:05.170  1      AD-CREATE       43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-10 11:49:16.670  1      ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-10 14:23:27.577  1      ADM-DESKTOP     43
Ajay Singh  2012-02-08 11:14:02.247  1      ADM-DESKTOP     43
```

What I need is to total the day up not the week my query totals the week.. here is what I have so far

```
select (e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Lastname) as name, p.date_entered, p.durhr, p.part_no, th.TotalHours

from  ProdUseExt p
JOIN Employee as e on e.employeeid = p.employeeid
JOIN (select employeeid, sum(durhr) as totalhours from ProdUseExt where date_Entered between '2/5/2012' and '2/11/2012' group by employeeid) as th on th.employeeid = p.employeeid

where e.OSVendor ='myVendor' 

and p.date_Entered between '2/5/2012' and '2/11/2012'
group by  e.Firstname,e.Lastname, p.date_entered, p.durhr, p.part_no, th.TotalHours
order by e.Firstname,e.lastname, p.durhr
```

Comment: I see what your say rushing Don't help I fixed the columns name.  but I not following your second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, 
CONVERT(DATE, ) will convert it to the date data type removing the time. 
The subquery join is also unnecessary

```
select (e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Lastname) as name, CONVERT(DATE, p.date_entered) p_date_entered, p.part_no, sum(P.durhr) as TotalHours
from  ProdUseExt p
JOIN Employee as e on e.employeeid = p.employeeid
where e.OSVendor ='myVendor' 

and p.date_Entered between '2/5/2012' and '2/11/2012'
group by  e.Firstname,e.Lastname, CONVERT(DATE, p.date_entered), p.part_no
order by e.Firstname,e.lastname, p.durhr
```

Comment: Ok I see now were I was making my mistake along with making this way  more complicated than it needed to be, I really appreciate it.